# natural log of fraction of sums in terms of sums of logs of fractions

Tags: statistics, logarithms

Given $n$ time series $P_{i_t}$ and a time series $P_t = \sum_{i=1}^n P_{i_t}$ with natural $t$ such that $1\le t\le T$ , we make new time series $$R_{i_t} = \ln \frac {P_{i_{t+1}}}{P_{i_t}}$$
and $$R_t = \ln \frac {P_{t+1}}{P_t}$$

Is there any relationship between $R_t$ and all the $R_{i_t}$ in terms of sample variances/covariances?

For the $P$ timeseries, we can write $$\operatorname{Var}(P_t)=\sum_i \sum_j \operatorname{Cov}(P_{i_t}, P_{j_t})$$

Is there some similar relationship for the $R$ timeseries?